# How to remove a particular migration in Entity Framework Core 2.0?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

I have added around 100 migrations using `Add-Migration` in Package Manager Console and run `Update-DataBase`. Now I want to remove let's say 56th number migration. I have not found any way to do this. EF Core allows me to remove migrations sequences only, which is I think correct. because If I remove an in-between migration, later migration might fail due to dependency on old migrations. But If there is no dependency it should allow me to remove or disable.

I know my question can be invalid, But I'm asking just for the curiosity.

Comment: Waiting for some good  answers from experts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> EF Core allows me to remove migrations sequences only, which is I think correct. because If I remove an in-between migration, later migration might fail due to dependency on old migrations.

Exactly.

> But If there is no dependency it should allow me to remove or disable.

It's infeasible for EF Core to go through every migration and figure out if there is a dependency, especially for SQL statements.

## How to remove a particular migration?

There's an answer to this though!

If you are sure there is no dependency, create an empty migration, then copy the "Up" and "Down" in the 56th migration into the opposite ("Down" and "Up") of the new migration.

This is what Git does too: to reverse an old commit, create a new commit that does the opposite.

Comment: Are you sure this will work correctly? The snapshot won't be changed by creating a new/empty migration and the follow up migration will be based on the snapshot and as if the changes are there. Imho the correct way would be to apply revert the changes in the model/fluent configuration and then create an migration based on that changes. This should update both, the snapshot and the migration file

Comment: i.e. if you added "name" property to a model and marked "age" as required, you'd remove these changes on the model add new migration

Comment: @Tseng Aaron has suggested this solution if the currently removing migration has no dependency in other later added migration

Comment: @viveknuna: You can try it, but I remember having issues when migrations are not in sync with the snapshot, like that the next migration create migrations expecting the removed or changed fields to be there as defined in snapshot. This of course do not apply to purely SQL changes which do not affect the model, such as adding stored procedures or updating them. new migrations are always based on the current snapshot + current state of the model, not on migration files. Migration files are just there to apply the update to the database

Comment: And manually updating the snapshot file to be in sync with the migration can be a pain in the ass too

Comment: This answer still requires you to manually update the migration to remove the old migration.  There needs to be a solution to correct inadvertent migrations being applied to the DB across branches that is easier than basically doing it manually in 5 steps.